# How do I load data automatically from another server everyday

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ssh

Hi I need to create something automatic that connects to another server using a php library and then I need to load the data in a mysql database only the first file uploads a new file is uploaded everyday. The problem is how do I continue uploading a file everyday to the database I am almost there

Here is the code:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php';

//connection to linux server
$conn = ssh2_connect('xxx.xxx.xx.xxx', 22);
$destinationPath = '/path/to/destination/path/';
$localPath = 'C:\path\to\local\path\';

//checks if the connection is successful or not
if(ssh2_auth_password($conn, 'username', 'password')){ 
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Authentication was successful");   </script>'; //javascript pop up when successful
  }else{
    die("Authentication failed");
}

if(ssh2_scp_recv($conn, $destinationPath, $localPath)){ 
echo '<h2>Todays file recieved</h2>'; //if file was recieved from server to   local echo todays file recieved, putting the file in localpath
}else{ //if the file was not uploaded send an email for radar file too be  uploaded

$to = 'testemail@yahoo.co.uk';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = "From: The Sender Name <senderEmail@yahoo.co.uk>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: senderEmail@yahoo.coom\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

}

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://localhost/Prototype/core/edit.txt', 'r');//get contents of file from web used to read the file
$myFile = 'C:wampwwwPrototypecoreedit.txt';//file directory
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Could not open: " .mysql_error());//open the file
fwrite($fh, $string);
fclose($fh);
$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$myFile'". "INTO TABLE `restartdata` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ");
  if (!$result) {
     die("Could not load." . mysql_error());
    }else{
 echo 'data loaded in the database';
     }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is?

Comment: Basically a file uploads everyday to the linux server and I need to fetch it everyday and store in a database

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared, Parameterized Queries.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not using PHP. And definitely nothing that's home made. There is a built in mechanism for that. It's called [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) tried and tested over more than 15 years and it's being used on thousands of installations.

> Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master)
>   to be copied to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves).
>   Replication is asynchronous by default; slaves do not need to be
>   connected permanently to receive updates from the master. Depending on
>   the configuration, you can replicate all databases, selected
>   databases, or even selected tables within a database.

To do this in PHP would mean the entire database is dumped daily or hourly during which means the site is unresponsive during the time the dump is being made. Then you have to transfer the whole database over HTTP.

Last but not least your PHP approach does not allow continous archiving. If you are archiving once a day, what happens if the system fails 23:50 hours after the last backup was made?

Comment: well it is too late it is a web application so it is best if it is php and I have done most of the technical errors just this left

Comment: Like I said thousands of web applications are being replicated as I type this.

Comment: well I am a graduate so not that experienced but you can do it in php

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: well I need to display this on a interface so php will have to be the one plus I only have few errors left

Comment: Good luck, I hope you will mark the answer correct in one years time when you eventually make the switch to replication.

Comment: thanks its just we use basic technologies at university