# How to backup database entirely from local database to host database in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, laravel

I'm using laravel and mysql as database, and I want to make a backup database in hosting with one click button in html, but I wonder what is the best query for them instead of query all data in all table with loop, then insert it one by one to host with loop. Thanks before

Comment: Wat? you do mysqldump and specify the database, you dont loop or anything.

Comment: Oh my bad, I mean with code, not a command :)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655929/how-do-i-load-data-automatically-from-another-server-everyday/38656052#38656052

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysqldump`

```
$ mysqldump -h <host> -u <user> -p<password> <database_name> > backup.sql
```

This will create a sql file `backup.sql` with all your data.

Note the missing *space* beween `-p` and `<password>.`

It's okay to give the password interactively (in which case, you'll have to skip the `<password>` part), but since you mentioned **laravel** in the question, I am assuming you want to code this and want it to be non-interactive.

EDIT:
Using code

Execute the command with `exec()`

```
$cmd = "mysqldump -h <host> -u <user> -p<password> <database_name> > backup.sql";
exec($cmd, $output, $return_value);
```

Comment: Thank you, but with code I mean, so I dont need to touch the command prompt :|

Comment: You won't need to if you specify the password.